# Variable that keeps track of integers in an array

Tags: arrays, c

Part of my assignment is to write a function that takes 10 integers and if the user hits any other keyboard(letters) it goes back to main menu. The integers that the user entered should be available for other functions too(so I guess that I need to create a variable in main that keeps track of integers).

For example if the user decides to only enter 6 integers and then hit "c" the program should go back to main menu and know that there are 6 integers stored and next time user tries to enter more integers only allow 4 more.

I've been struggling  for two days and I know the code is bad, but here it comes.
My function for entering integers.

```
int enter(int a[], int n){
    int i;
    for( i=1; i<n;i++){
    printf("Enter measurement #%d ", i);
    if(scanf(" %d", &a[i]) == 1){
    }
    else{
        printf("Exit!"); 
        break;
    }   
} main();
```

}

My variables in main.

```
int nrOfMeasurements;
int measurements[10];
```

And my function in menu. If user hit "e", user can enter integers. This if statements is nested inside a while-loop.

```
if(ch == 'e'){
    enter(measurements,10);  
    nrOfMeasurements = enter(measurements,nrOfMeasurements);
}
```

Comment: Don't call `main` in your own code, it's a really bad habit. It's probably also the cause of your problems.

Comment: Also remember that array indexes start with `0`. The loop `for( i=1; i<n;i++)` will skip over the first element in the array.

Comment: I understand, but If I just break; then it does not return to the menu. This was the only way I know of.

Comment: How about a loop in the `main` function?

Comment: Oh it's even worse than I thought: You call the `enter` function *twice* when you should call it only once. The second time you assign the returned value to a variable (whose value we don't know anything about) you also pass to the function. *And* the function doesn't actually return a value, and since you now call `main` in an indirect recursion the function won't even return! ***And*** you don't even attempt to return a value from the function, so when you remove that call to `main` you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: First of all, update the `enter` function to return the value of `i`. Secondly call `enter` only once, and assign the result to `nrOfMeasurements`, as in `nrOfMeasurements = enter(measurements,10);`

Comment: It works better now, thank you! The problem now is that if I only enter 4 integers and then click any keyboard to go back to many, it continues to fill the array with random numbers untill there are 10 integers.

Comment: @lata27 "it continues to fill the array with random numbers untill there are 10 integers. " ==> The array always has 10 `int`.  Post code that shows how you determined  _it continues to fill_.

Comment: I understand that, but then it means that I cannot use array in my function. I need a function that take a maximum of 10 integers. Maybe I should try to make function that takes in integers and stores it in array in main. Is it possible?

Comment: @lata27 "means that I cannot use array in my function" is an incorrect conclusion.  IAC, `int a[]` in `int enter(int a[], int n)` is not an _array_, but a _pointer_.

Comment: Related: [Back to menu with a character instead of an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73825451/back-to-menu-with-a-character-instead-of-an-integer) and [Program that stores maximum 10 integer values and displays them after user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73937285/program-that-stores-maximum-10-integer-values-and-displays-them-after-user-input).

Answer (score 0):

**Non-numeric input not consumed**

When a non-`int` text is entered, code fails to consume that input, leaving for later code to consume.  This is likely an issue.

**Return value save, but not used**

`nrOfMeasurements` after `rOfMeasurements = enter(...)` apparently unused as OP reports "it continues to fill the array with random numbers".

**`EOF` not detected**

End-of-file nor input error detected.

**Off by 1**

`for( i=1; i<n;i++)` will iterate `n-1` times, not `n` times.

**Code fails to return a value**

`int enter(int a[], int n)` should have a `return` someplace.

**Unneeded space in `scanf(" %d", &a[i])`**

`"%d"` consumes leading white-space.  `" "` serves no purpose here.

**`main()` lacks return type**

**Pedantic: `int` vs. `size_t`**

Extreme array sizes may exceed the `int` range.

**Save return value**

`enter(measurements,10);` should save return value.

---

Sample fixed code

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t enter(int a[], size_t n) {
  size_t i;
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("Enter measurement #%zu ", i + 1);
    int match_count = scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    if (match_count == EOF) {
      return (size_t) EOF;
    } 
    if (match_count == 0) {
      // Consume rest of line.
      int ch;
      while ((ch = getchar()) != `'\n'` && ch != EOF) {
        ;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  return i;
}

#define N 10

int main(void) {
  size_t nrOfMeasurements = 0;
  int measurements[N];

  ...
  if (ch == 'e') {
    nrOfMeasurements = enter(measurements, N);
    if (nrOfMeasurements != (size_t) EOF) {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", measurements[i]);
      }
    }

    // Last goal left for OP: 
    // "and next time user tries to enter more integers only allow 4 more."
  }
...
}
```

---

- Better code would use `fgets()` for all user input.
- Use `strtol()` rather than `"%d"` to well detect overflow of values outside `int` range.

Comment: Thx! I tried it but it does not work the way I described it. For example when the we call the function enter(); the user should be able to enter only 4 integers and then hit 'c' to go back to menu. Then if the user wanted to call the function enter() again user should be able to do that and enter 6 more integer (10 in total). So when the user enters 4 integers and then goes back to the menu those 4 integers should be saved. But when I try to do it, it automatically fills with random numbers since we specified int measurements[10];

Comment: @lata27 No, "it" (the function `enter()`) did not automatically fill the array with random numbers.  Those random numbers existed before the call.  Your code needs to only print assigned values.  Use the return value from `enter()` to know how many array elements were assigned.  Still hoping to see [code that shows how you determined it continues to fill.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73799348/variable-that-keeps-track-of-integers-in-an-array/73801183?noredirect=1#comment130315599_73799348).  Review [mcve].

Comment: I have to use what I've learn so far, so I cannot use size_t, strtol() etc. This is what my enter function looks like(I don't know how it is gonna look in comments.)                                int enter(int a[], int n){

    for(int i=1; i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter measurement #%d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]); 
    }  
}

Comment: @lata27 `scanf()` is how you read the data.  Since you asserted that "it automatically fills with random numbers", that implies some output.  How did code _output_ values including those random ones?

Comment: and this is my if-statement. If the user click 'e' in the  menu the user can enter integers.       if(ch == 'e' && numberOfMeasurements != max ){
           numberOfMeasurements = enter(measurements,max);
        }

Comment: I enterd 4 integers and when i clicked on 'k' it continued Enter measurement #5: Enter measurement #6: Enter measurement #7: Enter measurement #8: Enter measurement #9:   Then when i chose "view" in the menu it first showed 4 integers that i entered and then random nubmers like this.  1 22 22 22 -906819744 479 938399814 32764 -906816600 479

Comment: @lata27 1) looks like your code still indexes from 1 and not 0.  2) Comment <Last goal left for OP:  "and next time user tries to enter more integers only allow 4 more."> appears to have been ignored. Calls to `enter()` should use something _like_ `numberOfMeasurements +=enter(measurements + numberOfMeasurements, N - numberOfMeasurements);`.

Comment: I was just experimenting with 1 and 0, I changed it back to 0. I tried your code too it does not work. It continues Enter measurement #0: 2
Enter measurement #1: 2
Enter measurement #2: e
Enter measurement #3: Enter measurement #4: Enter measurement #5: Enter measurement #6: Enter measurement #7: Enter measurement #8: Enter measurement #9:   The idea is that it stops after e and goes back to the menu.

Comment: @lata27 Your comments lack the big picture and do not report the return value  of `enter`.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: I have started over from scratch 4 times already, sadly it did not help. Since the comments cannot show the code properly I can "Answer Question" with my whole program, where you can better see what the problem with the code is.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void view(int a[], int n);
int enter(int a[], int n);

int main (){

int max = 10, numberOfMeasurements;
int measurements[max];
char ch;

while(ch != 'q'){

    printf("\nView(v)Enter(e)Compute(c)RQ: "); 
    scanf(" %c", &ch);

    if(ch == 'v'){
        view(measurements,numberOfMeasurements);
    }
    if(ch == 'e' && numberOfMeasurements != max ){
       numberOfMeasurements = enter(measurements + numberOfMeasurements, max);
    }
    }  return 0;
}

void view(int a[], int n){
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      printf("%d ", a[i]); 
    }     
}

int enter(int a[], int n){

for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
    printf("Enter measurement #%d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);  
}  
}
```

Comment: Why value does `numberOfMeasurements` have the first time `enter(measurements + numberOfMeasurements, max);` is called?  It is not set to 0 any place.

Comment: `int enter(int a[], int n) { ...}` does not return a value.  Save time.  Enable all warnings.

Comment: I tried with numberOfMeasurements = 0. But the outcome was the same.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &a[i])` does not have its return value checked.  Code does not know if `scanf("%d", &a[i])` succeeded.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).